# Should I handle the error of WSARecv() in two places?

Tags: c++, sockets, iocp

When I call `WSARecv()` (or another Overlapped IO function), I could get an error immediately or I can get an error when I call `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` to dequeue a completion packet.

So is it accurate to assume that I must handle the error returned (for example: `WSAECONNABORTED`) in these two places, or even if `WSARecv()` returned an error immediately, I will also receive the same error when calling `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` and so I can only handle it in one place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A completion is only generated if you have a `SUCCESS` return or an error return where the resulting error is `IO_PENDING`. Any other error situation must be handled at the call site for the API in question, so at the `WSARecv()` call site. Once an overlapped operation has been started (`SUCCESS` or `IO_PENDING` returned from original API call) then this may also fail with an error which will be reported through the return value from `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()`.

So, YES, you MUST handle errors in the correct places.

Comment: +1 clear answer, by the way, very good elaboration on http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2015/01/wsarecv-wsasend-and-thread-safety.html, do you plan second part more on WSAsend()?

Comment: Once I've investigated the WSASend() side of that issue some more I may write some more. Right now I am just assuming that the same problem is possible and acting accordingly.